# Send data from sidekiq to rails controller without saving in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have `some_controller` with `some_action` including.
In the action I pass some data to a sidekiq job:

```
DoSomething.perform_async("some data")
```

How can I get the result of `DoSomething.perform_async` back to the controller without saving in a database?

Simple `Rails.cache.write('result')` in sidekiq job and `Rails.cache.read('result')` in `some_action` don't work.

Answer (score 2):

Sidekiq and rails run in separate [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), so they can't share memory. If you can't share memory, you have other options:

1. filesystem
2. object storage service (e.g. [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/))
3. database (e.g. redis)
4. [signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal)

The database is the most common choice, but a filesystem or object storage is more appropriate for many tasks, like image processing. Signals have limited functionality and I only list them here for completeness.

> Simple Rails.cache.write('result') in sidekiq job and Rails.cache.read('result') in some_action don't work.

Maybe you are using [ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memorystore), which wouldn't work across processes, because processes don't share memory. There are other cache stores, but be aware of the trade-offs before switching.